# Using "Application.DisplayAlerts = False gives "Method or Data Member not found" compile error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a module in Access to format cells in an Excel spreadsheet.

```
Sub FormatData()

Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Users\john.doe\Documents\scripts\apps\allow\Weekly_Cash_Trending"

Workbooks("Weekly_Cash_Trending.xlsx").Activate


Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
Range("A1").Select

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\john.doe\Documents\scripts\apps\allow\Weekly_Cash_Trending"
End Sub
```

It works, but it gives a pop up to confirm saving the file.

[Excel message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfQOs.png)

When I change the code to use "Application.DisplayAlerts"

```
Sub FormatData()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Users\john.doe\Documents\scripts\apps\allow\Weekly_Cash_Trending"

Workbooks("Weekly_Cash_Trending.xlsx").Activate


Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
Range("A1").Select

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\john.doe\Documents\scripts\apps\allow\Weekly_Cash_Trending"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I get the following error: Method or Data Member not found

[Method or Data Member not found Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq8d2.png)

I am new to VBA coding (obviously), can anyone help me resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You are coding this in Access, so my understanding is that `Application` in this context is `Access.Application` (not `Excel.Application`) -- and `Access.Application` has no `DisplayAlerts` member (unlike Excel).
- You appear to be calling `Workbook.SaveAs` method to save over the workbook itself. Use `Workbook.Save` if needed (it also means you don't need to toggle `DisplayAlerts`). Alternatively, `Workbook.Close` has a `SaveChanges` parameter to which you can pass `True` or `False`.

I think the code below (I wrote and tested in Access) should do what you were after.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub FormatData()
    With New Excel.Application ' Add reference to Excel Object Model for early binding
        '.Visible = True ' Uncomment if you want to see it happening

        With .Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\john.doe\Documents\scripts\apps\allow\Weekly_Cash_Trending")
            .Worksheets(1).Range("C:C").NumberFormat = "$#,##0"
            .Close True ' Passing True here means we want to save changes as we close the workbook
        End With

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Based on your code, I assume you already added a reference in Access for Excel's object library. If not, in Access, open the VB Editor, then `Tools > References > Scroll down in the list to Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library (or something like that) > Tick it > OK`.

I assume you want to change the number formatting of the cells on the first worksheet. If that sheet has a name, it's better if you refer to it by name (than by index like I did).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response! Yes I was able to get it working based on your advice chillin. Thanks for the help!!!