# Downloading a file using Internet explorer 11 automatically using vba

Tags: vba, automation, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to download file using InternetExplorer.Application, but it always opens a window asking to save or open the file. Is there a way to circumvent this and have it run and save in the background? Here is a block of code I have tried.

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "https://pastebin.com/raw/terAweb"
State = 0
Do Until State = 4
DoEvents
State = ie.readyState
Loop
Dim file: file= ie.Document.Body.innerHTML
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **URL Monikers** *API* instead of trying to communicate with the *InternetExplorer Application* might be simpler. 
Was that specifically done for Pastebin? Because it doesn’t really work with it, as far as I know. But I guess you can use another one

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFileA Lib "URLMON" _
 (ByVal pcaller As Long, _
  ByVal szurl As String, _
  ByVal szFileName As String, _
  ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
  ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As LongPtr

Sub Example()
Dim Download$

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Download = URLDownloadToFileA(0, "myURL", "C:\Users\Name\Downloads\test.txt", 0, 0)

    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:

    MsgBox Err.Number & " " & Err.Description

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello GoldMachine, thanks for take the time to write. I am aware of the URLMonikers API, but looking for a solution that works within Internet Explorer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following sample code, after using the getElementbyId method to find the download button, it will display the download prompt, we could using the `Application.SendKeys "%{s}"` command to click the Save button.

```
Sub downloadfile()

        Dim IE As Object, Data As Object
        Dim ticket As String

        Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate ("https://dillion132.github.io/default.html")

            While IE.ReadyState <> 4
                DoEvents
            Wend

            'Trigger the download button to download the file
            IE.Document.getElementbyId("btnDowloadReport").Click

            'wait the download prompt appear
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

            '
            Application.SendKeys "%{s}"

        'Waiting for the site to load.
        'loadingSite
        End With
        Set IE = Nothing
    End Sub
```

The web page content:

```
<a id="btnDowloadReport" href="https://research.google.com/pubs/archive/44678.pdf" download>Download</a>
```

Comment: Hi Zhi Lv, this code gives an error. Did you try running it?

Comment: Yes, it work well on my side, can you tell me the error message? Try to set debugger to check your code and find out which line throw this error message?

Comment: Compile error. Application.wait and .sendkeys gives, method or data member not found.

Comment: Please check whether you have already added a reference in Access for Excel's object library (if not, open the VB Editor, then Tools > References > Scroll down in the list to Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library (or something like that) > Tick it > OK). Here is a [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55669569/), you could refer to it.

Comment: The code doesn't work as expected, I fixed the problem using a different method.

Comment: Congratulation. can you post your solution and mark it an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.